# Optional field is marked as ng-invalid

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have this form group (using reactive forms) that I have set up.

```
this.transactionForm = fb.group ({
      'location': [null, Validators.required],
      'shopper': [null],
      'giftMessage': [null],
      'retailPrice' : [0, Validators.required]
    });
```

As you can see shopper and giftMessage do not have Validators.Required set on them, I want them to be optional fields. The rest of the form is required.

What I'm curious about is... when the page loads, all the fields are set to ng-invalid including the optional fields shopper and giftMessage above. Unfortunately, when it comes to submit the form, I pass in transactionForm.valid into my submit function and the form is invalid because the optional fields were not selected.

I'm a bit confused on why these optional fields are marked as ng-invalid in the first place? What can I do to prevent invalid form for optional fields inside my form group?

Here's how I set up my select for example:

```
<select [ngModel]="null" formControlName="shopper" style="margin-left:35px;" required>
            <option value="null" disabled selected>{{'SelectOption' | translate}}</option>
            <option *ngFor="let shopper of shoppers">{{shopper | translate}}</option>
        </select>
```

And here' what I noticed happen at runtime... these are the classes that get added to the field: `class="ng-touched ng-pristine ng-invalid"`

I've tried to add these to my constructor:

```
this.transactionForm.controls['shopper'].markAsTouched();
this.transactionForm.controls['shopper']..setErrors({incorrect: false});
```

I'm still getting ng-invalid for that control.

Comment: You're using reactive forms, but you have [ngModel]="null" on your select. ngModel is for template-driven forms. And setting it to null doesn't make sense. And you've set `required` on your select, although you precisely want it to be optional.

Comment: @JBNizet can't believe I didn't notice the required. I'm an idiot. Thanks! I removed that. I set ngModel because I need select placeholders and I saw an example that used ngModel in order to get the select placeholder to show up for the dropdown.

Comment: What do you mean by "select placeholder"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<select [formControl]="transactionForm.get('shopper')" >
  <option [value]="null">{{'SelectOption' | translate}}</option>
  <option *ngFor="let shopper of shoppers" [value]="shopper" >{{shopper | translate}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Like someone mentioned above, I removed the required I accidentally put on it and that works. I'm wondering if above is best practice for using reactive forms (do not use ngModel for the select placeholders?) Thanks!

Comment: Do not use ngModel with ReactiveForms. Only [formControl], [formGroup] and [formArray] directives. Keep the ngModel for template driven forms. With reactive forms you specify whether the form is required or not, during the control intialization, in your component class.

Comment: @Tomasz Kula: you can use ngModel with ReactiveForms without any problem and use ``[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"`` where applicable.

Answer (score 0):

For optional inputs when using reactive forms you can tell angular to not consider some input by using `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"`

so in that case you can add `[(ngModel)]` for your input, but you can remove `formControlName` from it.